# How to protect directories

Tags: permissions, download, directory, file-permissions, web

I have uploaded different Microsoft Word documents to the directory `http://www.mywebsite.com/documents/`

Now the problem is that when I browse to this url you can see all my documents in a list but they need to be hidden and only aproachable by a given link (for example `http://www.mywebsite.com/documents/document1.doc`)

Any idea how I can do this? Is it OK to place a index.html in every documents directory so they get a blank page, or does Google not like this?

Comment: On most web servers, putting an `index.html` in a directory prevents it from being listed, but there may be other, cleaner solutions to the problem.

Comment: @larsmans, this works only if index.html is set as default document for directory.

Comment: @ValerioManfredi: I forgot the essential word *most*, edited the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using IIS, make sure you have unchecked the "Allow Directory Browsing" in the directory properties.

If you are using Apache, read this

[Apache configuration](http://www.techiecorner.com/106/how-to-disable-directory-browsing-using-htaccess-apache-web-server/)

Comment: Thanks Valerio. Exactly what I needed, the Apache configuration works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

you can disable directory browsing using .htaccess file if you use apche.

just add the below line into your .htaccess file

[Options -Indexes](http://thewarehouseclub.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/how-to-protect-directory-browsing-in-your-website/)

This will disable the directory browsing in your website.